# elasticsearch: multiple fields with boosts

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a query for elasticsearch. The conditions: there is always a customer filter. There is a field "name" that should create the highest score if matched, the next best field should be "category" and then "description". But a result should be returned even if the search doesn't find anything in "name" or "category", but only in "description".

What I tried:

```
        $query = [
        'filtered' => [
            'filter' => [
                'term' => [ 'customer' => $selectedCustomer ]
            ],
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'should' => [
                        'match' => [
                            'name' => [
                                'query' => $val,
                                'boost' => 7
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'should' => [
                        'match' => [
                            'category' => [
                                'query' => $val,
                                'boost' => 3
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    'should' => [
                        'match' => [
                            'description' => [
                                'query' => $val,
                                'boost' => 1
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

But this seems to return only results with a match in "description". What am I doing wrong? Any hints?

Comment: That series of three `should` is creating a single array containing the three `match`es? (like `"bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "FIELD": "TEXT"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "FIELD": "TEXT"
          }
        },
        {}
        ...
      ]
    }`)

Comment: ....yeah, now that I look at it, of course that makes sense. But how would I do it correctly?

Comment: I don't know php, but I'm sure that's how that query should look like.

Comment: I posted an update, thanks to your input I managed to update the query - the only problem left is the matching to entire words

Comment: Ok. Provide the complete mapping of those three fields, what data you put in them and what query are you expecting to match.

Answer (score 0):

seems like I found a solution to the first problem by doing it like this:

```
        $query = [
        'filtered' => [
            'filter' => [
                'term' => [ 'customer' => $selectedCustomer ]
            ],
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'should' => [
                        ['match' => [
                            'name' => [
                                'query' => $val,
                                'boost' => 7
                            ]
                        ]],
                        ['match' => [
                            'category' => [
                                'query' => $val,
                                'boost' => 5
                            ]
                        ]],
                        ['match' => [
                            'description' => [
                                'query' => $val,
                                'boost' => 1
                            ]
                        ]],

                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

The next problem though is that this finds only matches for entire words. Like, if $val = 'bread' I get all the matches which contain the word "bread", but I do not get stuff like "gingerbread". Anyone know any solutions to this?